# Failed in compare decode() of subprocess with string

Tags: python, string, subprocess, webhooks

My script failed in compare `check.decode() == 'TRUE'`, the result of `/healthcheck/bin/captureFailed.sh` is **TRUE**, should enter inside the `if`, and not fall into the `else`, any suggetions ?

**Script python:**

```
import requests
import json
from time import gmtime, strftime
import subprocess
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT

try:

    p = Popen(['/bin/bash', '/healthcheck/bin/captureFailed.sh'], stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)    
    check = p.communicate()[0]
    print("[INFO] CHECK TEPS STATUS: {}".format(check.decode()))

    if str(check.decode()) == 'TRUE':

        print("[INFO] SENDING ALERT")

        webhook_url = 'https://hooks.slack.com/services/channel-here'

        response = requests.post(
            webhook_url,
            json={'text': '[ALERT] Baseline control has not been updated, there is a flaw in TEPS, check the logs. [{}]'
            .format(strftime("%Y-%m-%d", gmtime()))},
            headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
        )

        if response.status_code != 200:
            raise ValueError(
                'Request to slack returned an error %s, the response is:%s'
                % (response.status_code, response.text)
            )

        else:

            print("[OK] SENT WITH SUCCESS")

    else:

        print("[OK] NO ERRORS, RUNNING SCRIPTS ...")


except Exception as e:

    print('[FAILED] Caused by: {}'.format(e))
```

**Script shell:**

```
cat /healthcheck/logs/exec.log | grep HTTP | while read line
do
    echo "$line" | grep "ERROR" >/dev/null
    if [ $? = 0 ]; then
        echo "TRUE";
    fi
done
```

**Output:**

```
[INFO] CHECK TEPS STATUS: TRUE

[OK] NO ERRORS, RUNNING SCRIPTS ...
```

Comment: No need for *str.*  What about: `if check.decode().strip() == "TRUE":`?

Comment: I will check, thanks!

Comment: perfect, sucess, comment your awnser, please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When working with external commands (executed via *subprocess* or others) output, and in some other cases, it's recommended not to forget that strings (even if they look *OK*), might contain the "invisible" *EOLN*s.

Example:

> ```py
> >>> s = "abcd\n"
> >>> s
> 'abcd\n'
> >>> len(s)
> 5
> >>> print(s)  # Looks OK
> abcd
>
> >>> s == "abcd"
> False
> >>> s.rstrip() == "abcd"
> True
> ```

The solution is to strip the end of line, using ***rstrip()***. 
An additional comment you should only call *decode()* once.

Below it's the corrected code:

```py
# ...

check = p.communicate()[0].decode()
print("[INFO] CHECK TEPS STATUS: {}".format(check))

if check.rstrip() == "TRUE":

# ...
```